# Colon in the method

Tags: c#, methods, syntax, constructor

Just trying to confirm my understanding of a colon in a method. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071148/what-does-this-colon-mean) post which explains that the code after the colon is run before the called method.

Does this mean with the [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors) below that Shape is run before Circle? And Circle is run before Cylinder?

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public const double pi = Math.PI;
    protected double x, y;

    public Shape(double x, double y) => (this.x, this.y) = (x, y);
    public abstract double Area();
}
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(double radius) : base(radius, 0) { }
    public override double Area() => pi * x * x;
}
public class Cylinder : Circle
{
    public Cylinder(double radius, double height) : base(radius) => y = height;
    public override double Area() => (2 * base.Area()) + (2 * pi * x * y);
}
public class TestShapes
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        double radius = 2.5;
        double height = 3.0;

        Circle ring = new Circle(radius);
        Cylinder tube = new Cylinder(radius, height);

        Console.WriteLine("Area of the circle = {0:F2}", ring.Area());
        Console.WriteLine("Area of the cylinder = {0:F2}", tube.Area());

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/* Output:
Area of the circle = 19.63
Area of the cylinder = 86.39
*/
```

Comment: Yes, the base constructor runs first.

Comment: @Plutonix what a time to be alive! (if that was the case)

Comment: BTW there is **no** *colon* in any *method*.  There is a *colon* in your *class definition* however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constructors (function names with the same name as the class name), the : indicates that a constructor of the base class will be called and will execute first, with any passed parameters, before the code of the child constructor.

So for the function `public Cylinder(double radius, double height) : base(radius)` the constructor for Circle is executed before the code in the Cylinder constructor, which in turn calls the constructor for Shape setting `this.x` and `this.y`, and then executes its own code, which it has none, and then finally the code in Cylinder constructor is executed, setting `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. When you create an instance of `Cylinder`, the constructor of `Shape` is executed first, initialising `x` and `y`. Then the constructor of `Circle` is executed, initialising `radius`. Finally, the constructor of `Cylinder` is executed, changing `y` to `height`.

Note that this `: base` syntax only works on constructor. It doesn't work on ordinary methods. For ordinary methods, you do this:

```
public void Method1() {
    base.Method1(); // to call the base class implementation first
}
```

And this pattern of calling the base class constructor before anything else makes sense, doesn't it? Each subclass is a specialisation of their direct superclasses. So it makes sense to first "construct" the superclass, then "construct" the more specialised subclass.