# In C# what category does the colon " : " fall into, and what does it really mean?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get reference in the Microsoft Developer website about what the function of the : really is but I cant find it because it seems that it is neither a keyword or a operator so what is the function of the colon in C#? Also I have seen it being applied to a Method how does that function?.

Comment: It's a character that is a part of expressions/statements, including the ternary operator and the case statement.  What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338398/thisfoo-syntax-in-c-sharp-constructors

Comment: Not duplicate. That was asking about extending constructors not the purpose of `:`

Comment: This question not very useful IMO. It's like asking "what is the purpose of the character 'a' in C#" and getting a list of "var", "class", etc

Comment: @Blorgbeard Attempting to denigrate this question as being like "_what is the purpose of the character 'a'_" is utterly absurd. As per the accepted answer, `:` has ***very specific semantics*** depending on a number of possible contexts.

Comment: So what? So does `a`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Colons are used in a dozen fundamentally different places (that I can think of, with the help of everyone in the comments):

- Separating a class name from its base class / interface implementations in class definitions

  ```
  public class Foo : Bar { }
  ```
- Specifying a generic type constraint on a generic class or method

  ```
  public class Foo<T> where T : Bar { }

  public void Foo<T>() where T : Bar { }
  ```
- Indicating how to call another constructor on the current class or a base class's constructor prior to the current constructor

  ```
  public Foo() : base() { }

  public Foo(int bar) : this() { }
  ```
- Specifying the global namespace (as *C. Lang* points out, this is the [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx))

  ```
  global::System.Console
  ```
- Specifying attribute targets

  ```
  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
  ```
- Specifying parameter names

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(value: "Foo");
  ```
- As part of a ternary expression

  ```
  var result = foo ? bar : baz;
  ```
- As part of a `case` or `goto` label

  ```
  switch(foo) { case bar: break; }

  goto Bar;
  Foo: return true;
  Bar: return false;
  ```
- Since C# 6, for formatting in interpolated strings

  ```
  Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}");
  ```
- Since C# 7, in tuple element names

  ```
  var foo = (bar: "a", baz: "b");
  Console.WriteLine(foo.bar);
  ```

In all these cases, the colon is not used as an operator or a keyword (with the exception of `::`). It falls into the category of simple syntactic symbols, like `[]` or `{}`. They are just there to let the compiler know exactly what the other symbols around them mean.

Comment: The generic type constraint answers the OP's interrogation about methods. `DoSomething<T>(T foo) where T : IEnumerable`

Comment: In addition to calling the base constructor, you can use it to call another overload of the current class' constructor.  eg: `public Foo() : this("value passed as argument") { }`

Comment: @SimonTewsi / retailcoder Thanks I've included those alternate uses for completeness. They're sneaky little things--I forgot how often I used them.

Comment: So you might say that a colon is a way to qualify a type when the qualifier is too complex to fit in a single keyword, sort of how colons precede subtitles of books?