# : (colon) in c# for Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

I'm new at C# and Unity and reading the Manual and encountered a foreign colon syntax in some examples:

```
function Choose(probs: float[]) {
var total = 0;

for (elem in probs) {
    total += elem;
}

var spawnPoints: Transform[];

function ChooseSet(numRequired: int) {
var result = new Transform[numRequired];
```

It's from [Random Numbers Unity3d Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RandomNumbers.html)

I found this question: [Multiple Meanings of : in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034475/in-c-sharp-what-category-does-the-colon-fall-into-and-what-does-it-really?lq=1)

But no one of the examples in this question seems to fit.

I think, it's a kind of type definition... but normally it would be

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
```

instead of

```
var spawnPoints: Transform[];
```

so I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sample is in Unityscript (almost same as javascript or actionscript 3). The syntax is littlebit different, than syntax of C#.

Your tip is right.
The

```
var spawnPoints:Transform[];
```

is in Unityscript and in C# it's exactly

```
Transform[] spawnPoints;
```