# What does the colon mean?

Tags: c#, windows, class

I have a class header:

```
public class Person : Human
```

What does the `:` mean?

Is it something like the extends in Java? And what do I need it for?

Comment: While it has been already answered I believe that it's a so basic question and you shouldn't come to StackOverflow to ask something you can check on MSDN...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ":" means "extends" if you're comparing it to java.
Every class extends object by default.
You need it to extend a class, I'm assuming you already know what extending is, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: It can also mean "implements", for interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the colon operator is separating the class name "Person" from the base class "Human". The colon here implies inheritance, so you are right! Person inherits the fields/methods of Human. You can also add other methods to Person to provide it with additional functionality.

Here is a similar post with other functions available with the colon operator: [In C# what category does the colon " : " fall into, and what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034475/in-c-sharp-what-category-does-the-colon-fall-into-and-what-does-it-really)

Answer (score 0):

The colon operator (`:`) is used to extend a class, like in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). This means that a `Person` is a specific kind of `Human`. It can participate in any context that relates to a `Human` (such as being passed as a method argument), but may have specific behaviors (i.e., it may override some of `Human`'s method, or add new ones).

Answer (score 0):

The ':' operator is used for inheriting from a super class(Synonymous to the 'extends' keyword in Java).

Why is inheritance needed - It's a really powerful concept for modelling the relations in the world around us. Technically, the subclasses tend to be more specific and the superclasses are more generalized.
For example - Consider `Student : Person`. Here the Student is the subclass and the Person is the super class.

```
class Person
{
  public string name;
}

class Student : Person
{
  public string id;
}
```

This translates to the fact that Every Student is also a Person and a student will inherently have 'name' as an attribute. But every Person needn't be a student and won't have 'id' implicitly.